# Using stubs in a basic Java maven project

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, stubs

I have a basic maven project with the folder structure: -main and -test directories.

I have one package in the main source directory which consists of a few classes, say a.class b.class and c.class, all under the same package. All classes have dependencies to each other. To do proper unit testing, and to cut the dependencies from each class, I write stub classes of each a, b and c class, define them to have the same package and put them inside the test source directory. Then I run: mvn test

Fine, the stubs are now being found first from the classpath and used, but I want to modify the classpath (on the fly?) so that, when testing class a, I need to have the original a.class and stubs used for b.class and c.class. Similarly, when testing class b, I need to have the original class b and stubs used for a.class and c.class.

How do I accomplish this using Maven and JUnit?

This is kind of frustrating in Java, because in C++, one can use the makefile source path and user defined include paths in unit test header files to force the stubs to be found first and then explicitly add an include to the original class to be tested.

Comment: Sounds like you are going the wrong way. I would suggest to start using Mocking...and don't implement Stubs yourself. Furthermore the classes from `src/test/java` are the ones which are first on the classpath. Apart from that if you need to modify the classpath on the fly there is something wrong in your design. Can you make a simple example project and put it for example on Github so we can make better suggestions...

Comment: Might be a good idea to look into mocks, e.g. using a library like Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependent classes you schould use interface for each class. Then you can resolve dependency problems actually...

Answer (score 0):

Like @khmarbaise already pointed out you are going the wrong way. In Java it is good practice to use Mocking libraries like [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) and [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) if you want to test static methods.

Those libraries help you to write Stubs for your existing classes without to modify the classes themselves. Check [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mockito%22) for Mockito. You can include it with maven via

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then using JUnit you end up writing Mocks for your existing classes. There are many tutorials regarding Mockito [out](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) [there](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-mocking-java).